# Parsing PHP Web Service Replt In Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am new to Swift but am trying to use a PHP based web service that returns a reply :-

```
{
    responseData =     {
        1 =         {
            name = "3D SYSTEMS CORP";
            result = success;
        };
        10 =         {
            name = "ABERCROMBIE & FITCH CO-CL A";
            result = success;
        };
   };
}
```

I have assumed this is a valid JSON format but have not been able to work out how to load this data which is just a list of strings into an string array. I have trie code such as this to iterate one rte elements but with no success.

```
let url = urlComponents.URL
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if let urlContnet = data
    {
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContnet,  options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            if let nudges = jsonResult["responseData"] as? NSArray {
                for nudge in nudges {
                    print(nudge)
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            print("ERROR")
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

can anyone help

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here

1. Your JSON is malformed. You can check the validity of JSON at:
   http://jsonlint.com

There are several issues in your JSON. The corrected JSON is here:

```
{
    "responseData": {
        "1": {
            "name": "3D SYSTEMS CORP",
            "result": "success"
        },
        "10": {
            "name": "ABERCROMBIE & FITCH CO-CL A",
            "result": "success"
        }
    }
}
```

2. responseData is a dictionary and not an array. Change your code to process this dictionary instead of array.

HTH

Comment: Thank you , I am using a third party web service so cannot control the format , is there any way to process this using the current response format , thank you for your help